# Pasar una clase de manera dinamica en un objeto Intent

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo un `ListView` de manera dinamica. Al hacer click en cualquier opcion, se conecta a una base de datos para que traiga el nombre de una clase. Mi duda esta en como mandar ese nombre de manera dinamica a un objeto `intent` y me direccione a esa clase que manda la consulta.

Comment: cuando le das un click a la lista mandas un intent??? existe un metodo intent.putExtra y mandas el string... creo q eso segun lo q yo entiendo te debe servir

Comment: Te sugiero agregar el código que tienes realizado, la clase que manda la consulta es una Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te ha dicho Alex puedes enviar datos en un Intent con el método putExtra, por ejemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NuevoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("title", title);
intent.putExtra("message", message);
startActivity(intent);
```

En este ejemplo en el intent para cambiar a NuevoActivity envias dos extras llamados title y message en los que se envía las varibales title y message, y luego podrías recibirlo y guardarlo en variables de esta manera:

```
tituloRecibido = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
mensajeRecibido = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
```

En este caso ambos extras que se envían son Strings.

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara y si esta respuesta es la correcta para el OP, esto ya fue preguntado anteriormente, **[enviar datos entre Activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Enviar+datos+entre+activities)** ayúdanos a cerrar estas preguntas como duplicados. ahora falta responder: ¿como me direccione a esa clase que manda la consulta?